# Javascript to Set Other Attribute Required if Specific Selection Option Chosen

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function namereq(elem){
    if(elem.value == 1){
        var required = document.getElementById("name").attributes.required = true;}
}
   if(elem.value == 0){
   var required = document.getElementById("name").attributes.required = false;}
}
</script></head><body>

<p>Please select a detail level option.</p>
<select 
    required
    id="toggle_detail" 
    name="toggle_detail"
    oninput="namereq()">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value=1>Recommended</option>
    <option value=0>Not Recommended</option>
</select>
<input    
     type="text"
     id="name"
     name="name" 
     placeholder="Name"> 


</body></html>
```

What I'm trying to do...

By Default input id="name" is not required.  If selection Option Value = 1 is selected for the id="toggle_detail" question, then Javascript (not JQuery) will change the attribute of id="name" to required.  Otherwise, Javascript will revert id="name" to not required if the Option Value = 2 is selected.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

document.getElementById("name").required = true;

Or

document.getElementById("name").required = false;

Comment: This did the trick.  I was spending like a half hour trying different combinations of code and was a bit confused about what type to use.  After some time I learned that the required was actually a boolean.  I think at first I attempted that without the boolean qualifier, now after using this with the boolean, works like a charm.  I'll select your solution when the system will allow me.

Comment: @Ryan enjoy then